# php return to $.ajax in submit login form (jquery ajax does not working when returning with php json_encode)

Tags: php, ajax, json, authentication

I have a login form in php(login.php).Onsubmit action of the form calls the function  as named checkLogin() in javascript.

**login.php**

```
<form onsubmit='check_login();return false;'>

Username : <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your user name..."  />
Password : <input type="text" id="password" name="password"   placeholder="Enter your password..." /
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="enter" value="Enter"/>
```

I have also have a javascript page as named js.js.The Javascript page has $.ajax call (json).

**js.js**

```
function check_login(){
    alert("in the check_login");
    alert($('#username').val()+$('#password').val());
    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url:"_checkLogin.php",
        data:"username="+$("#username").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val(),
        error:function(error)
        {
            alert("error   :"+error);
            },
        success:function(response){

            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                alert(obj.success);

            if($obj.success==true){
                alert(obj.success);


            }
            else if(obj.error){
                alert(obj.error);

            }
            else if(obj.error){
                alert(obj.error);

            } 
            else
                alert("else");

        }


    });
};
```

Another page I have is _checkLogin.php and $.ajax call the php page to check username and password.

**_checkLogin.php**

```
<?php


session_start();
include_once("_dbConnect.php"); // provide coonnection
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['password']));


if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){ 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password='$password'");
 $num_row = mysql_num_rows($query);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($num_row>= 1){




        $_SESSION["login"] = "true";
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row[1] ;
        $_SESSION['surname'] = $row[2];
        $value=array("success"=>true, "session"=>"mehmet");
        $output=$json->encode($value);
        echo $output;



        }
    else if($num_row< 1){

        echo json_encode(array("error"=>"Invalid login provided."));

        }

   }
   else {

        echo json_encode(array("error"=>"You must enter a username and Password."));


        }

?>
```

When I execute the login.php page I got an error as

> error :[object Object]  error status 200

Can anyone help me? What I do wrong.I couldn't find the problem.Or what is the alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

Fix this line:

```
if($obj.success==true){
```

Delete $ before obj variable.

Comment: I did as you said, the problem continues unfortunately.